# Why can I do "delete p;", but not "delete (p+1);"? Why does delete require an lvalue?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, delete-operator

On [this page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-zero), it's written that

> One reason is that the operand of
>   delete need not be an lvalue.
>   Consider:

```
delete p+1; 
delete f(x);
```

> Here, the
>   implementation of delete does not have
>   a pointer to which it can assign zero.

Adding a number to a pointer shifts it forward in memory by those many number of `sizeof(*p)` units.

So, what is the difference between `delete p` and `delete p+1`, and why would making the pointer `0` only be a problem with `delete p+1`?

Comment: Strstroup recommended that C++ compilers set the pointer if it is an lvalue to NULL. I personally think some not-null constant would have been more appropriate for finding double delete bugs but even so ...

Comment: Because the result of the addition is an rvalue, and you cannot assign an rvalue. Same reason you can't say (1 + 1) = 4.

Comment: @GMan: What about `int *a = new int(10); *(a + 1) = 5;` then? Here also `p+1` would be a pointer.

Comment: This isn't about assigning the target of the pointer (which just got freed), this is about redirecting the pointer itself.

Comment: in your code, `a+1` is an rvalue, but `*(a+1)` is an lvalue, and that's what you assigned to. Stroustrup is talking about `delete` zeroing the pointer, not the pointee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do `p + 1 = 0`. For the same reason, if you do `delete p + 1` then delete cannot zero out its operand (p+1), which is what the question on Stroustrup's FAQ is about.

The likelihood that you'd ever write `delete p+1` in a program is quite low, but that's beside the point...

Comment: @Steve Jessop: So, this has nothing to do with `p+1` not being allocated using `new()`?

Comment: In the context of Stroustrup using it as an example for that FAQ question, no. In practice, if `p+1` results in an address that was allocated with `new()`, because `p` was obtained by subtracting 1 from that address, then in standard C++, `p` is not a valid pointer, and it is actually undefined behavior even to add 1 to it. Not something you'd expect to find yourself relying on. So the example was not a realistic one - Michael Mrozek's `p-1` is better. I think Stroustrup just picked `p+1` as an example of an lvalue, not as an example of something you'd actually delete.

Comment: "Example of an rvalue", I mean. Oops.

Answer (score 5):

p and p+1 point to different places, as you rightly said `sizeof(*p)` units apart. You can't delete something that hasn't been allocated, but for example:

```
A* p = new A();
p++;
delete p-1;
```

would delete the original allocation. Deleting p+1 when p+1 wasn't allocated originally is undefined; glib flips out with:

```
*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804b009 ***
```

The implementation can't zero p+1 because p+1 isn't a variable to modify. The paragraph was saying that

```
delete p;
```

could be translated to

```
free(p);
p = 0;
```

That doesn't make sense with p+1

Comment: The first part of your answer is irrelevant - this has nothing to do with whether 'p+1' is a valid pointer. The point is that it's not an lvalue.

Comment: What? He asked two things, the first was "what is the difference between delete p and delete p+1"

Comment: @Andrew Medico: is it not an `lvalue` because we did not allocate memory for it using `new()`, or for some completely different reason?

Comment: @eSKay They're unrelated. lvalues are values that have an address, and can therefore appear on the left side of an equation. `p` has an address, as it's a variable. `p+1` doesn't; the value `p` points to is summed with 1 and that temporary is used inline, but it isn't stored permanently in memory somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* `delete` a rvalue. Nothing in the spec (n3242) does preclude it. In practice, it [gives no error](http://ideone.com/FdYpn).

BTW if the article says

> operand of delete need not be an lvalue

it means it may, or may not be a lvalue. It doesn't say the operand cannot be a lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that neither of those are lvalues so setting them to NULL (or any other value) is simply not possible.

Comment: `f(x)` *might* be an lvalue, it just isn't necessarily one. `f` could return `T*&` for some type T, in which case it's an lvalue. Or it could return `T*`, in which case it's an rvalue.